# error C2039: 'Dispose' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::ErrorProvider'

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, errorprovider

I am trying to use ErrorProvider Class to show error on checkbox. I am able to show the error using the following code

```
errorProvider1->SetError(checkBox1,"Error");
```

But when I am trying to dispose this errorProvider using the following code

```
errorProvider1->Dispose();
```

Then this line is showing error

```
error C2039: 'Dispose' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::ErrorProvider'
```

This Code I am able to run successfully in vc# but not in vc++;

But since My requirement is to use this in vc++.

Can anybody please tell me what is the problem in this code.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617.aspx#vs05cplus_topic5), the `IDisposable` pattern is different in C++/CLI, and you cannot implement or call `Dispose()` methods in that language.

You have to use the `delete` operator instead:

```
errorProvider1->SetError(checkBox1,"Error");
delete errorProvider1;  // Equivalent to errorProvider1->Dispose().
```

Comment: Better yet, just declare `errorProvider1` with stack semantics so no `delete` call is necessary at all.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Thanks for your reply now it is working fine.

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks for reply... How can I use errorProvider1 with stack semantics. Can you explain or give any example.

Comment: @MayankPrabhakar : You need to show where and how `errorProvider1` is declared. :-] E.g. if it's at class scope the answer will be different then if it were in block scope.